# dh_usrlocal: ... is not a directory

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm working on a Makefile setup to create a debian package:

```
.PHONY: package
package: $(PACKAGE_TARGETS)

build/%.changes: ../%.changes
        mkdir -p build
        for f in `<$< awk 'BEGIN { files = 0; } { if (files) print $$5; } /^Files:/ { files = 1; }'`; do \
            test -f build/$$f || mv ../$$f build/; \
        done
        mv $< $@

../%.changes:
        dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc
```

Everything was working fine with the build until I made a very small commit. Which adds an executable file at `/src/bin/app-cli`. Then references that executable in the debian install file `debian/app.install`:

```
src/bin/app-cli usr/local/bin
```

For some reason making that change caused the build system to generate the error:

```
dh_usrlocal: debian/app/usr/local/bin/app-cli is not a directory
rmdir: failed to remove 'debian/app/usr/local/bin': Directory not empty
dh_usrlocal: rmdir debian/app/usr/local/bin returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [binary] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/jenkins/data/workspace/app-VBJPWWOTACEEMDGNNWMFS4QU6K4EPG5PJRESMEIZPZL4GAUCKWVQ'
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
make: *** [../app_0.0.1-13-master_amd64.changes] Error 2
```

Does anyone know this new file is being treated as directory by Debian Helper?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`dh_usrlocal` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debhelper/dh_usrlocal.1) might help you understand what’s going on.

Debian packages are allowed to install directories under `/usr/local`, but the best way to do so is to use maintainer scripts. `dh_usrlocal` automates this by transforming directories under `/usr/local` into maintainer script snippets. It assumes these directories are empty, since Debian packages aren’t allowed to install *files* under `/usr/local`.

In your package, `dh_install` follows your instructions and copies `app-cli` to `/usr/local/bin` (inside your package). `dh_usrlocal` then runs, sees the directory, creates the appropriate maintainer script, then tries to delete the directory (so it isn’t shipped as such in the package) — and fails since it contains a file.

Comment: You’re supposed to package binaries in `/usr/bin` (or `/usr/games` for games). The answer I wrote was intended to answer Philip’s question, not provide a generic “how to package binaries”. If you’re having trouble packaging something, feel free to [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: my apologies -- a bit frustrated; I am sure you have been there.  cleaned up; thank you.

Comment: added a question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542285/dpkg-debuild-dh-helper-how-to-symlink-binaries-installed-in-opt-package-to-us

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but installing the executable at `/usr/app-cli` instead fixed the problem.

I think something to do with Debian packages not having access to `usr/local/bin/`.