# Dpkg Debuild dh_helper: How to symlink binaries installed in /opt/package to /usr/local/bin?

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging

I am packaging my first debian project, and I have things 100% worked out with `gnu-make` (anything is possible here, for me, and so my difficulties right now are exclusively in navigating the `dpkg`/`debuild` system).

I have, right now, just some dummy compilations in place with the following rules file and compatibility:

```
// debian/compat
10

// debian/rules

#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
  dh $@

override_dh_auto_install:
  cat binaries.txt | xargs -I arg install -D -m 0755 arg $$(pwd)/debian/package/opt/package/arg
```

Assume that all compilations and source files are managed via make in the directory containing `debian` directory perfectly -- I have a minimal case that works just as expected.

```
// binaries.txt
foo
bar
```

is just a binaries file that lists out the dummy binaries my trivial make process produces.

I am attempting to code a `deb_helper` symlink to symlink my binaries in `/opt/package` to `/usr/local/bin` according to the documentation here:

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg-maintscript-helper.1.en.html

But I am not having much luck.  What is the procedure on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ship symlinks in your package, I would recommend using [`dh_link`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debhelper/dh_link.1). The easiest way to do that is to list the symlinks you want in `debian/links` (or `debian/package.links` if your source package builds multiple binary packages):

```
opt/package/bin/foo usr/bin/foo
opt/package/bin/bar usr/bin/bar
```

Debian packages aren’t supposed to ship any files under `/usr/local` so the build tools don’t support that too well.

If you don’t need anything else in `/opt/package`, you could install your binaries directly to `/usr/bin`.

You can also use [`dh_install`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/debhelper/dh_install.1) to simplify your installation, by listing the binaries you want to install in `debian/install`:

```
foo opt/package/bin
bar opt/package/bin
```

or

```
foo usr/bin
bar usr/bin
```

You can then drop the `dh_auto_install` override.

Comment: with respect to the "debian/install" file, is this interpreted like the rules file, or can this be rendered interactive--for example, I prefix with a hash-bang for bash and evaluate a find command?

Comment: It can be made dynamic, as can any `debhelper` file: make it executable, add the appropriate shebang, and ensure the resulting output matches the expected format (so something like `find ... -printf "%f usr/bin\n"`).